# Dash Cytoscape drag and drop callback

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I need callback when I drag and drop a node. I saw documentation, but I didn't find any information about the parameter for dragging.

I have tried all the parameters from https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/reference but none of them are triggered when I drag the node

Full code https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape/blob/master/usage-events.py

And I also saw this topic https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-cytoscape-returning-node-positions-from-layout/23818/3 , but I don't understand how I can get data from browser console

```
@app.callback(Output('tap-node-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'tapNode')])


@app.callback(Output('tap-edge-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'tapEdge')])


@app.callback(Output('tap-node-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'tapNodeData')])


@app.callback(Output('tap-edge-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'tapEdgeData')])


@app.callback(Output('mouseover-node-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'mouseoverNodeData')])


@app.callback(Output('mouseover-edge-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'mouseoverEdgeData')])


@app.callback(Output('selected-node-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'selectedNodeData')])


@app.callback(Output('selected-edge-data-json-output', 'children'),
              [Input('cytoscape', 'selectedEdgeData')])
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?  where is the code ?

Comment: @D.L
I have tried all the parameters from https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/reference but none of them are triggered when I drag the node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to use "drag" event in cytoscape.js library. Do you have any progress in your task?